# Команда git push выдает ошибку

Tags: git, github

я сначала склонировал проект и внес туда кое-какие изменения, теперь я хочу запушить свой проект и ввожу следующее:

```
 git push origin master
```

и в результате выдает это:

```
git: 'credential-cache' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
To https://github.com/Assylzhan91/ishop.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/Assylzhan91/ishop.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Вопрос: должен ли я  сначала запулить  и зачем мне пулиться, ведь я склонировал проект изначально, или ошибка не того характера??

Comment: Я полагаю, за это время в проект запушили новые коммиты?

Comment: ну в любом случае я должен коммитить сперва, а потом пушить

Comment: @John, `git commit` и `git push` - разные вещи. Вы указали на проблему с push. И решение - сделать `git pull`, чтобы получить изменения с удаленного репо, затем разрулить конфликты, если они будут, снова закоммитить, и только затем - запушить.

Comment: @John, я имела в виду, что за это время кто-то другой запушил коммиты в мастера, поэтому теперь вам нужно стянуть изменения, прежде чем пушить свои